# remove the zeros from an array with a function Python

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy

Here's the deal, i have an array of multiples elements with about half of it being zeros. I want to remove these zeros by using a function instead of the traditional `x=x[x!=0]`.

I tried:

```
def funct(x,y):
    x=x[x!=0]
    y=y[y!=0]
```

But the output i get is the same variable i had before i execute the function. An array with multiple zeros.

I'm new with python so sorry if this question sound ridiculous.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x[x!=0]` returns a new array, and you assigned that new array to a local variable `x`.

You can do:

```
def funct(x, y):
    x = x[x!=0]
    y = y[y!=0]
    # do something here
    return x,y
a, b = funct(a, b)  #assign the returned value back to the global variables
```

Comment: I think, it would return only one element, not a list. (For Python lists)

Comment: This is NumPy. The objects are ndarrays, not lists.

Comment: @SukritKalra Question is tagged `numpy`.

Comment: @Everyone : Sorry. Forgot to see that. +1. :)

Comment: Alright thank you very much for the answer! Sorry for that easy questions :P! Have a nice day everyone!